# CodeIgniter: How to get the number of records before get all results?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I need to get the number of records for a query before apply a limit. I tried with the following code:

```
$db = $this->load->database();
$this->db->select($this->select_column)
         ->from($this->table);
echo $this->db->count_all_results();
```

But count_all_results don't return any number. If I excecute $this->db->get(), I obtained a result sets, but first I need to apply a limit.

What can be happenning with $this->db->count_all_results()?
Is there another solution for get the count of rows returned based on the previews query?

I'm using Codeigniter 3 with MySQL.

Comment: I think you can do that directly in SQL, you might juste use the `$this->db->query("")` function

Comment: try printing the query using echo $this->db->last_query(); and show us the query

Comment: The most efficient way is to execute a `select count(*)` directly against the database first and use that value for your real query.

Comment: I don't believe you're allowed to chain a `->from()` to a `->select()`.  See `$this->db->from()` on this page where it's NOT chained to a `select()`.   https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html

Comment: I followed the @Nicolas suggestion, it works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing the the following first to get the count:

```
$this->db->select('count(*) as ct');
$count = $this->db->get($this->table)->result()[0]->ct;
```

Now your variable **$count** has the count you need to apply the limit, so you can

```
$this->db->.... // Your code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->load->database();       // Database is lodaed 
$query = $this->db->get('table_name');
 return $query->num_rows();

// This will return count of total rows
//After that you can return the result

return $query->result();
```